# How to remove white spaces from Android SDK's path

Tags: android, android-studio

How to remove white space from Sdk path??
I have changed the user name from control panel but that was not fruitrul.

[image]

Comment: You tried to rename your folder name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution : 1**

you can `Rename` the folder name and then change the path according `Rename`.

**Solution : 2**

you can copy the all file in **/sdk** directory and and delete in file in this directory and reinstall `SDK` in other folder and path and paste all that file there.

Answer (score 0):

try it renaming your folder

> Basit Khaleeq

to

> BasitKhaleeq

```
C:\Users\BasitKhaleeq\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message tells you, you can keep the problematic SDK path if you aren't planning to use NDK.

Still, it would be wise to specify the path without spaces. You can use the short path reported by `dir /x` command:

```
C:\Users\BASITK~1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```